# How to get event value from Google tag API

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am using Google tag API to count the number of times an offer is displayed on a customer's screen (impression) for an e-commerce website. I will then show the total view count (impression) of each offer to the vendors.

I call the below each time an offer is viewed by a customer.

```
window.gtag('event', 'offer_view', { 'offer_id': offerID });
```

I can see these values on the dashboard so the event is sent properly. However, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference#event) does not specify something to fetch the overall event data.

I tried

```
window.gtag('get', 'offer_view', 'offer_id', testCallBack);
```

but the callback function is not even called.

I also would prefer to present a list of offer_id and get view counts for those rather than loading the whole event data if possible. I would be grateful if you could provide some guidance/pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gtag` get is only available when you set something first.

If you data is provided with event then it can not be get.

---

This offer_view idea should be done through some database work.

Or you want to use the number from Google Analytics 4?

Then you need to use the GA4 Data API but still not a good choice on this scenario because you will expose the API information on the JS.

Overall, you need a 3rd party like GA4 to store the data and can be retrieved safely.

---

If you want to get the data from GA4 Data API

Just give the

```
Dimension : customEvent:offer_id
Metrics : event_count
Filter : event_name = ${The event with offer_id}
```

Please follow some document

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema

Check the GA4 rerpot `offer_id` should already be set as an event parameter.

Comment: Many thanks for your help Darrel. Would you recommend to call GA4 data API from my server and provide the data back to the user then? If so, is there a way to get event count and total users via GA4 data API? I see those at the dashboard but the data API only return the event value i.e. offer_id which is useless without the event count.

Comment: If you do have the backend on your own then it might be a good practice. 
The GA4 Data API is almost like how you use the explorer report. 
You can choose the dimension and metric you want.